# How to downgrade from php 7 to 5.6 on Fedora 25

Tags: php, fedora, downgrade

I have installed Fedora 25 on a server and need to downgrade php from 7 to 5.6.
I have done the following:

```
dnf remove php
dnf remove php-common
wget https://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/remi-release-25.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-25.rpm
dnf --enablerepo=remi install php56 php56-php-common php56-php-cli php56-php-mbstring php56-php-mcrypt php56-php-pear php56-php-xml php56-runtime php56-php-mysqlnd
```

Everything worked fine but now everything is named php56 instead of php and so the system can't find anything.  For example:

```
# php -r "echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();"
-bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory
# php56 -r "echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();"
Current PHP version: 5.6.30
```

How do I take the last step and make everything (including packages) work like before?

I tried creating a symlink as follows, but php code does not run from the web, so the apache->php link is broken.

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/php php
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to install and use docker to easily use legacy packages.

Comment: If I install docker will all the thousands of lines of php code start working?  Or do i have to reprogram everything to use docker containers?

Comment: It will just work out of the box, you just need to pick the right image, like https://hub.docker.com/_/php/, and use volumes to mount your local code into the container. Also you should check docker-compose for easy management. I'd say it's really worth the trouble!

Answer (score 3):

This is how Software Collections are designed: parallel installation without altering base system and allow multiple versions. So /usr/bin/php is not provided on purpose.

You can read [My PHP Workstation](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation).

For **mod_php** (apache module), if you can remove "php" (base package) and install "**php56-php**" (which is missing in your list), it will work out of the box. If you can't remove "php", you can disable its LoadModule directive (/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php.conf), so the php5 module will be loaded (/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php56-php.conf).

For **FPM** (FastCgi server), when **php56-php-fpm** service runs you only have to adapt the path to the socket in webserver configuration (apache, nginx or lighttpd)

For **CLI**, you can use the module command (and most applications will find php and related commands in the PATH)

```
$ module load php56
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2017 17:58:52)
```

And if you really want a single version, you can create the symlink, it will work:

```
$ ln -s /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2017 17:58:52)
```

Comment: Thank Remi! I finally found my missing piece was php56-php which installed the .conf file as you say and now phpinfo() confirms my Fedora 25 system is using php5.6.  FYI Your PHP Workstation page says to install php56-fpm but dnf finds 'No match' and I see no such package at http://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/25/remi/x86_64/ .. I know almost nothing about FPM and think I'm happy using mod_php.

Comment: Indeed it should be  php56-php-fpm, blog post fixed.

Comment: About FPM, you can read https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/05/30/PHP-Tour-2016-Clermont-Ferrand